# How to set a local notification to fire from a date stored in an array?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilocalnotification

Im making a remind app and the so far the user is apple to successfully submit and store data from a form which is then stored in an array, this array writes to a file when the app is closed and then the data is loaded from the file when the app is reopened.

I am having an issue because I'm wanting to set the notifications to remind the user to complete the task at a certain time and I am not able to recall the NSDate that is stored in my array. Also I want to make the app work so that the notification is repeated everyday.

Here is my TableViewController:

```
class MedicineTableViewController: UITableViewController {



//MARK Properties

var medicines = [Medicine]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Notifications Setup
    let reminderActionOkay = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    reminderActionOkay.identifier = "Okay"
    reminderActionOkay.title = "Okay"
    reminderActionOkay.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    reminderActionOkay.destructive = true
    reminderActionOkay.authenticationRequired = false

    let reminderActionOpen = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    reminderActionOpen.identifier = "Open App"
    reminderActionOpen.title = "Open App"
    reminderActionOpen.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    reminderActionOpen.destructive = false
    reminderActionOpen.authenticationRequired = true

    //Put the different types of notifications into a category
    let ReminderCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    ReminderCategory.identifier = "reminderCategory"
    ReminderCategory.setActions([reminderActionOpen, reminderActionOkay], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    ReminderCategory.setActions([reminderActionOpen, reminderActionOkay], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)


//MARK: Notification Schedule
func scheduleLocalNotification() {
    let localNotificationtime1 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotificationtime1.alertTitle = "Take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime1.alertBody = "It is time to take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime1.alertAction = "Show Details"
    localNotificationtime1.fireDate = medicine.time1 // 1 Day repeating
    localNotificationtime1.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotificationtime1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotificationtime1.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotificationtime1.category = "reminderCategory"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotificationtime1)

    let localNotificationtime2 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotificationtime2.alertTitle = "Take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime2.alertBody = "It is time to take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime2.alertAction = "Show Details"
    localNotificationtime2.fireDate = medicines.time2
    localNotificationtime2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotificationtime2.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotificationtime2.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotificationtime2.category = "reminderCategory"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotificationtime2)

    let localNotificationtime3 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotificationtime3.alertTitle = "Take",  medicines.name
    localNotificationtime3.alertBody = "It is time to take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime3.alertAction = "Show Details"
    localNotificationtime3.fireDate = medicines.time3
    localNotificationtime3.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotificationtime3.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotificationtime3.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotificationtime3.category = "reminderCategory"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotificationtime3)

    let localNotificationtime4 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotificationtime4.alertTitle = "Take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime4.alertBody = "It is time to take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime4.alertAction = "Show Details"
    localNotificationtime4.fireDate = medicines.time4
    localNotificationtime4.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotificationtime4.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotificationtime4.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotificationtime4.category = "reminderCategory"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotificationtime4)

    let localNotificationtime5 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotificationtime5.alertTitle = "Take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime5.alertBody = "It is time to take", medicines.name
    localNotificationtime5.alertAction = "Show Details"
    localNotificationtime5.fireDate = medicines.time5
    localNotificationtime5.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotificationtime5.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotificationtime5.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotificationtime5.category = "reminderCategory"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotificationtime5)


}

}
```

Here is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    // Point for handling the local notification when the app is open.
    // Showing reminder details in an alertview
    UIAlertView(title: notification.alertTitle, message: notification.alertBody, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    // Point for handling the local notification Action. Provided alongside creating the notification.
    if identifier == "ShowDetails" {
        // Showing reminder details in an alertview
        UIAlertView(title: notification.alertTitle, message: notification.alertBody, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    } else if identifier == "Okay" {

    } else if identifier == "Open App" {
        //Launches app when open app button pressed
        UIApplicationState.Active
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Here is my data model:

```
import UIKit

class Medicine : NSObject, NSCoding {


var name: String
var time1: NSDate
var time2: NSDate
var time3: NSDate
var time4: NSDate
var time5: NSDate


init?(name: String, time1: NSDate, time2: NSDate, time3: NSDate, time4: NSDate, time5: NSDate) {

    self.name = name
    self.time1 = time1
    self.time2 = time2
    self.time3 = time3
    self.time4 = time4
    self.time5 = time5

    super.init()


    if name.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am also getting an error for the alert body and title since I don't know how I chain together the string followed by the stored information in the array.

Btw this is my first swift project since learning the language from scratch so go easy on me if I'm being an idiot. :(

Answer (score 2):

Change these lines

```
localNotificationtime1.alertTitle = "Take", medicines.name
localNotificationtime1.alertBody = "It is time to take", medicines.name
```

to these

```
localNotificationtime1.alertTitle = "Take \(medicines.name)"
localNotificationtime1.alertBody = "It is time to take \(medicines.name)"
```

To add the time, add this code

```
localNotificationtime1.fireDate = NSDate(time1)
```

Comment: Tick the answer if this is exactly what you need